# Navigation Bar hiding when moving to new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I am trying to move from one view controller to other by pressing on a table view cell in the present view controller. The problem is when I do this :

```
FGTipViewController *vc = [[FGTipViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FGTipViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

It takes me to the new view controller but the navigation bar disappears. This happens for a particular view controller only and works fine for others. I am not able to make out any elementary difference between these classes. What could be the cause of this kind of problem? Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: I have tried writing [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO]; in viewDidLoad and init functions but to no avail.

Comment: Do you hide navigation bar anywhere?

Comment: No.. that is why its working in other classes.

Comment: Did you check with viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods?

Comment: Try to Set hidden:No, while you are about to push..FGTipViewController *vc = [[FGTipViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FGTipViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: @KumarKl what is diff between above comments and yours? mean, functionality wise?

Comment: @Mani Just to check, Before the (push)ViewController gets load.

Comment: @KumarKl k. I think, he did mistake in somewhere else?

Comment: Please see the answer below. Its a work around I had to add in viewDidLoad. Thanks for the comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it works. Thanks!

```
UINavigationBar* navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

    if (navBar) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
            [navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, navBar.frame.size.width, navBar.frame.size.height)];
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines when you push your view,

```
FGTipViewController *vc = [[FGTipViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FGTipViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

And also in the viewWillAppear method of FPTipViewController,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In FGTipViewController,

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {

    [super viewWillAppear];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}
```